# How do I update the Windows date and time to automatic using Batch?

Tags: batch-file

I work at as a technician and sometimes we Reinstall the OS. I have a batch script file that handles most of the initial setup (Like installing Chrome, etc). However I would like to set the Windows date and time to automatic. Is this possible using Batch?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatic"? Please explain.

Comment: On Windows 10, it is an option to set the date to automatic ( as in it connects to the internet and sets the date to current date) and time to the current time zone.

Comment: So it's about automatic time synchronization, huh?
Not directly related with batch, but this page can help you:
http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-3088594/disable-set-time-automatically-feature-windows-registry.html

Comment: Do these machines get joined to a domain?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what a domain is, however it is connected to our naz server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There maybe a way to be able to do this by Windows Powershell; however, I feel that it is would be very difficult and not as easily accessible. Furthermore, trying to do this with Batch seems even more out of reach. However, the automatic option you are referring is very likely to be an option that is somewhere in the Windows; thus the recommendation of Powershell.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Explorer09, you can change the Internet Time Settings through the registry.

```
:: Enables the option: "Synchronize with an Internet time server"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\Parameters" /v "Type" /t reg_sz /d "NTP" /f

:: Sets the name of the NTP server to "time.windows.com"
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\Parameters" /v "NtpServer" /t reg_sz /d "time.windows.com,0x9" /f
```

It's also possible to set the date and time manually.

```
date 05-17-2017
time 19:40:00
```